# SRD-12VDC-SL-C 8 relay module

Tags: power-connector

I am a novice and would like to know the name of the female plug that connects to the input pins.

Comment: The SRD-12VDC-SL-C is a 12V relay made by Songle in China. It's a component that gets soldered in to a PCB.  You had best provide a link and/or photo of the exact module you have in mind.

Comment: they are called "dupont wires", you need something like a "F-F 10CM dupont cable".

Answer (score 0):

This relay is designed to be mounted directly to PCB, not a socket.